# Return one result per person in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Assuming I have this graph in neo4j:

```
CREATE (a:Person {name: "Person A"})
CREATE (b:Person {name: "Person B"})
CREATE (r1:TestA {result: 1})
CREATE (r2:TestA {result: 2})
CREATE (r3:TestA {result: 3})
CREATE (r4:TestA {result: 3})
CREATE (a)-[:RESULT]->(r1)
CREATE (a)-[:RESULT]->(r2)
CREATE (b)-[:RESULT]->(r3)
CREATE (b)-[:RESULT]->(r4);`
```

How would I return only the best (being the Result with the lowest `result` property) result for each person?

If I do

```
`MATCH (p:Person)-->(t:TestA) RETURN p, t ORDER BY t.result LIMIT 1;`
```

I only get `(a)-->(r1)`, as expected, but I want to get `(a)-->(r1)` AND `(b)-->(r3 or r4)`.

Any hints on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a aggregation function in cypher:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:RESULT]->(t) RETURN p, min(t.result)
```

However this will not return a row for person not having a RESULT relationship. Using `OPTIONAL MATCH` can help with this.

Comment: Great - that's exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!